# How does the javascript confirm work?

Tags: javascript, html

Let's assume I've got form with such input :

```
<input type="submit" value="Delete" onclick="return window.confirm('Are u sure?');"/>
```

Here is my question, how does it work? When I click on 'Delete' and then "Cancel/No" in the dialog box the action delete is not invoking, but why? I understand that after we click the Delete input the event onclick will be raised, but dont get why it can stop raising the form action. Where does method window.cofirm return the boolean so it can stop invoking form action?

Comment: Clicking "cancel" makes [`confirm()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.confirm) return false to your `onclick` handler, which prevents the default action (submit).

Comment: OK returns true, cancel returns false, it doesn't get much simpler. The returned false value cancels the click event on the submit button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically if you return "false" in any event handler, it prevents the event's default action from happening. Returning "true" allows it to continue. Since the confirm function returns true when OK is clicked and false otherwise, it prevents the form from being submitted unless OK is clicked.

Comment: thanks, I knew that true/false will be returned but didnt know what for example such false do after that, now i see "false prevents default action from happening", thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

When you click cancel in the confirm box, your following code:

> onclick="return window.confirm('Are u sure?');"

converts into

> onclick="return false;"

that stops form submit.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> result = window.confirm(message);
> ```
>
> - `message` is the optional string to be displayed in the dialog.
> - `result` is a boolean value indicating whether OK or Cancel was selected (`true` means OK).
>
> — [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.confirm)